# How to add snippet script in angular html file

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

cli and bootstrap in component i use bootstrap tooltip
And it's note that Tooltips must be initialized with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Where i should add this in angular app generated by angular.cli, I should that in component.html or index.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use bootstraps component like tooltip, dropdown 
Then  ngx-bootstraps is there to use ready components of bootstrap

[Go with these steps](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/)

Second option is to install jquery to angular

[Typescript — Integrate jQuery Plugin in your Project](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc)

Comment: i install bootsrap and jquery and add to angular.json scripts section

Comment: Where i should add some snippet of script in angular

Comment: But there is no required to write scrip for tooltip

See the exmples at the end of page

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."> Button with tooltip </button>

Comment: Have you seen this post

https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Comment: i install ngx-bootstrap, now it's work fine, you re my hero, and thanks for attention :)